# Why does Coq.Init.Logic define the notation "A -> B"?

Tags: coq

The Coq Standard Library file Coq.Init.Logic, which can be found [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html), contains the statement

`Notation "A -> B" := (forall (_ : A), B) : type_scope.`

I don't understand how this is possible, given that the symbol `->` already has a built-in meaning. Is `->` overwritten by this?

If I type in `A -> B`, how does Coq know if I mean `A -> B` or `forall (x : A), B`?

Yes, I know the two propositions are logically equivalent, but shouldn't this be a theorem instead of a notation?

---

As you can tell, I've not had much experience with Coq, but I want to understand the details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `->` symbol is actually defined by the notation you found in `Coq.Init.Logic`!  While `forall` is built-in, `->` is defined using the notation system. The `Coq.Init.Logic` module is loaded automatically into Coq because it's exported by [Coq.Init.Prelude](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Prelude.html), which is why you immediately have access to it.

When you write `A -> B` it's interpreted using the notation, which is `forall (_:A), B`; this is syntactically similar to `forall (x:A), B`, except that the expression `B` isn't allowed to depend on `x`. There's no ambiguity - this is the only definition for `A -> B`, and indeed if you load Coq without the prelude (eg, by passing the `-noinit` flag) `A -> B` will not parse.

One aspect of Coq that makes `->` seem built-in is that the notation is *bidirectional* - it applies to both parsing and to printing. This is why you see `->` in your goals and when you use `Check` and `Search`. Here there is real ambiguity; in this case, if a `forall (x:A), B` has a `B` that does not depend on `x`, Coq prefers to print it using the notation rather than the built-in syntax. If you turn off printing of notations (`Unset Printing Notation.`) you'll see `forall (_:A), B` everywhere you used to see `A -> B`. Of course, if you have a function type with a real dependency, then Coq needs to use `forall (x:A), B` since `B` needs to refer to the variable `x`.